# How to exclude a redirect endpoint from swagger openapi

Tags: nestjs, swagger-ui, openapi

Im using nestjs. we have  root endpoint  `/`  which redirects to `/health` endpoint. since its just redirection, how to remove that from swagger?
Below is the code in app controller for `/` endpoint

```
@ApiExcludeEndpoint(true)
@Get()
@Redirect('/health')
index() {}
```

[image: swagger UI]

Tried using decorator from [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/decorators)

```
  @ApiExcludeEndpoint(true)
```

is not working

Comment: I tried. It worked for me. Can you share whole controller file

Answer (score 0):

The decorator works.

```
 @ApiExcludeEndpoint(true)
```

Issue was with redocly UI. had to restart redocly with `preview docs` command again!